# Netbeans 7.0, entering values with composite primary key

Tags: java, netbeans, master-detail, composite-primary-key

I am working on a project with MySQL database Java GUI.

This is my SQL script 
CREATE TABLE takenservice (
`ResvID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`ServID` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0  NOT NULL, 
`ServUsedDate` DATETIME NOT NULL
, `PayStat` VARCHAR(6) DEFAULT Unpaid  NOT NULL,
`ServRecBy` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
`PayRecBy` VARCHAR(7),
`Quantity` SMALLINT DEFAULT 1  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ResvID`, `ServID`, `ServUsedDate`));
Alter table takenservice 
add constraint foreign key (ResvId) references reservation (ResvID);
Alter table takenservice 
add constraint foreign key (ResvId) references reservation (ResvID);

---

I created the entity classes with Netbeans 7.0 and created 4 classes:

Service 
Reservation 
ServiceTaken 
ServiceTakenPK

but I cant enter values to the table and it gives me an error that I am trying to enter null values in as primary keys.

I have found the bug actually in Netbeans forum which is http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105084.

and accordingly I have added the following methods to the class ServiceTaken

```
public int getResvID() {
    return takenservicePK.resvID;
}

public int getServID() {
    return takenservicePK.servID;
}

public Date getServUsedDate() {
    return takenservicePK.servUsedDate;
```

upon inserting a new entry in the table I get this error :

Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO takenservice (PayRecBy, ServRecBy, Quantity, PayStat, ServUsedDate, ResvID, ServID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [ddd, ddd, 0, ddd, null, null, null]

---

What I can do to fix this ? Please help me with this I am running out of time =/

Answer (score 0):

Please try using 
     **System.out.println(yourqueryexecution stmt);**
then check whether the statement can be executed in the DB;
Find whether it sends all the values to the db;
hope this works..

Comment: the statement can be executed in the db. The thing is the values of the primary keys are not sent.